# AspNet MVC template issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm having some trouble with the asp.net "register/login system" that comes ready with the AspNet MVC template.
It worked great for me up until recently that I started receiving the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I tried running old versions of the code that used to work and they failed as well, I don't know what could have caused it.

Thanks ahead!
Eran

Comment: it looks like the SQL Server is not available. was anything changed in the connection string or the sql server was switched off, renamed, security configuration was changed etc... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the SQL Server service account

- If you are not using a domain account as a service account (for
  example if you are using   NETWORK SERVICE)

  you may want to switch this first before proceeding
- If you are using a named SQL Server instance

  make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings in your ASweb P.NET application
- Usually the format needed to specify the database server is
  machinename\instancename
- Check your connection string as well
- Check that you have connectivity to the SQL Server

. Note what you are using to connect: machine name, domain name or IP address? Use this when checking connectivity. For example if you are using myserver

```
Start > Run > cmd

netstat -ano| findstr 1433

telnet myserver 1433

ping -a myserver
```

more info at: http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur usually when you publish your project. This happens when there is problem in connection string and make sure you SQL server as well as SQL server browser are running.